AUTOSAR NM User Data Enabled for one CAN Connector and not for other CAN Connectors
I have one ECU with two CAN Connectors [CAN1 and CAN2] and two are on different NM CAN Clusters.
I want NM-USER-DATA_ENABLED value TRUE only for CAN1 while I want FALSE for CAN2.
Is that allowed according to AUTOSAR TPS Template?
If so how?
Because I don't see any relevant attribute under BusSecificNmEcu for this User Data parameter. Only under NmEcu as shown below.
Some example ARXML will help me a lot.
Shown below are snippets from Standard

